# logger.debug(...) is printing twice in log file

Tags: java, log4j

We have written some `logger.debug()` statements in code, but it's printing twice in below fachene.

> 2012-10-17 10:53:34,791, MessageListenerThreadPool : 0, [package
>   name], Entered the method(),  ,2012-10-17 10:53:34,791
>   MessageListenerThreadPool : 0 DEBUG [package name] Entered the
>   method()

Please help me why it's printing twice?

Below is my log4j configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">
    <appender name="infoLogsFile" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="Application.log"/>
       <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %t %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>   

   <appender name="fatalLogsFile" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
         <param name="File" value="Application_Func_Point.log"/>
       <param name="Threshold" value="FATAL"/>
         <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
             <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d, %t, [%c], %m, %n,"/>
         </layout>
   </appender>


   <appender name="custom" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
   <param name="File" value="Application.log"/>
   <param name="Append" value="true"/>
    <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>
   <param name="MaxFileSize" value="75000KB"/>
   <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="500"/>
   <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d, %t, [%c], %m, %n,"/>
   </layout>       
   </appender>
<logger name="com.unisys"> `
    <level value="debug" /> 
</logger>
   <!-- ======================= -->
   <!-- Setup the Root category -->
   <!-- ======================= -->
   <root> 
    <priority value ="debug" /> 
       <appender-ref ref="custom"/>
    <appender-ref ref="fatalLogsFile"/>
    <appender-ref ref="infoLogsFile"/>
   </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Youhave 2 appenders using the same file : "infoLogsFile" and "custom" are both linked to "Application.log", and both thresholds parameters have the value "DEBUG", which means anything you log at DEBUG level will be written twice